# MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity & SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-identity

I have the default Visual Studio 2013 MVC template. I'm getting an error "JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined" after I log in using ASP.NET Identity and navigate to the Match.cshtml page I created which is below. Any ideas why it's not seeing the jquery '$'?

[EDIT]
If I make a normal HTML page everything works so this somehow must be related to using a layout or something around that. I'm using the default templates _Layout page.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity


@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

<!--Add script to update the page and send messages.-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var clientID = "";
        var server = $.connection.gameServer;

        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        server.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {

            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();

            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };

        // get the ID from the server for our team
        server.client.responseID = function (id) {
            clientID = id;
        }

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            server.server.requestID();

            // todo: define all the GUI events that need to send requests to the server for validation
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                server.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());

                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
else
{
    <div>Please login!</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to wrap my scripts in my Match view inside the scripts section.

```
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.3.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/signalr/hubs")
etc...
```